# Maven Release Plugin Milestone Support

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, milestone

I have problem with maven release plugin.What i need to do is do tag this way [ **0.0.1** --> **0.0.1.M1** --> **0.0.1.M2** --> **0.0.2** ]. For that i need to use maven release plugin but it only supports snapshots.I want to know is there any way to do the milestone tag using maven release plugin.
Thanks

Comment: by using the [`tagNameFormat`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagNameFormat) you can change this.... What I don't understand is what you mean by: `...but it only supports snapshots`?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise thanks for your answer. What I mean next release version always will be 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT something like this.What I want is 0.0.1-M1

Comment: If you like `0.0.1-M1` can't be the next development version cause it's not a SNAPSHOT..Apart from that you can define `-DdevelopmentVersion=0.0.1.M2-SNAPSHOT` than the next step will be `0.0.1.M2`...The idea of the plugin is the usual version life time from SNAPSHOT to release..

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise thanks your reply.I think this is the best answer.There are no other way around to solve my problem.If you can put this as answer i will accept it.thanks

Comment: I would suggest to change your version simply to `0.0.1.M1-SNAPSHOT` afterwards the increment to `0.0.1.M2` should work with maven-release-plugin...

Comment: thanks can you put this as answer.Then I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to change the version you have in your pom file to:

```
<version>0.0.1.M1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

afterwards you can simply use `mvn release:prepare release:perform` to increment the milestone version...